# Excel order writing Arabic text and English Numbers

Tags: excel, arabic-support

Problem:
I have a sentence/word I need to past in an excel cell. It consists of an Arabic word, along with some numerical values (in English). For example, let's say I want to write the below

[image]

However, excel keeps returning the below

2,1 - الحدث

It you notice, the numerical values are always moved to the left of the word, while I want to keep it on the right.
I tried concatenating, but didn't seem to help. I am open to any solution, vba or not, as I have spent a lot of time on this with no luck.

Comment: Have you tried adding an **'** (apostrophe) at the start of the text?

Comment: i did, didn't work

Comment: I think it is an issue between right-to-left and left-to-right fonts.  Try Format Cells --> Alignment --> Right-To-Left --> Text Direction --> `Right-to-Left`.  If I copy paste what you show `Excel returning` into a cell with the correct text direction, the result is as what you show in `what I want`

Answer (score 0):

I added this keyboard to my device and it helped me with that.

Central Kurdish Keyboard

[image: 1]

Use it to write the numbers only, and use the normal arabic keyboard to write the rest of the text.

And note that it didn't work with the numpad, it worked only with the numbers row at the top - the one that has the special characters !@#$%^&*()